# Set [civicrm.files]

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I have a dev copy of CiviCRM that I upgraded to 4.7.21.  The file paths have been removed and show [civicrm.files] instead.  I cannot figure out how to set [civicrm.files] so that CiviCRM can see the *extend* directory and other files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specifically set the value of `[civicrm.files]` in `civicrm.settings.php` with code like this:

```
global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.files'] = array(
  'url' => 'https://example.com/foo',
  'path' => '/var/www/example.com/foo',
);
```

If you don't set the value, then Civi will try to find it automatically, but this doesn't work in all configurations. (For example, if your directory structure uses symlinks, it may not resolve correctly.)

**Tip**: You didn't ask, but if your system is basically working, then you can inspect the value of `[civicrm.files]` in a few ways:

- In the web UI, navigate to `Administer => System Settings => Directories`. Click on the main help icon.
- In the web UI, navigate to `Administer => System Settings => Resource URLs`. Click on the main help icon.
- In the CLI, run [`cv path -d [civicrm.files]`](https://github.com/civicrm/cv)
- In the CLI, run [`cv url -d [civicrm.files]`](https://github.com/civicrm/cv)

Comment: Thanks for this Tim!  CiviCRM on the System Status page suggests to me that I should make my resource URLs portable but the documentation says it should be absolute.

Does it matter?

Comment: Tim, thanks for the great answer.  I guess the plot thickens when CV reports I have the right paths.

Comment: If you can use variables like `[civicrm.files]`, I'd say do that. I'm not sure which doc recommends abslute, but I'd guess it was written before 4.7.0. TBH, it's as much taste/circumstance as anything.

Comment: @TimOtten https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Resource+URLs

Comment: I found that even though the paths were correct according to the CV command I still had to use the code above.  Also, I found that CiviCRM was adding /ext and my path was /extend.

Comment: Thanks Tim, still useful even after all these years!