# setting path and url for [civicrm.files]

Tags: system-status

after much digging around I have discovered that  [civcicrm.files] is set incorrectly for some reason during install.

i'm hoping this will go some way to explaining the odd and inconsistent system status behaviour i am seeing around system status messages

I've found a post here 
[Set [civicrm.files]](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19495/set-civicrm-files/19498#19498)
explainig how to set the variable during via the civicrm.settings.php file

still doesn't seem to have fixed my problem though so I am wondering if I have set the values correctly.

Do I need a '/' on the end of either / neither / both path and url?

Comment: @dkg112 it would be helpful to know what the current value of [civicrm.files] is set to.

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/#list-of-additional-settings has URL examples both with and without a trailing slash, paths without. Adding details to your question (what the incorrect values were after install and what you corrected then to) would help people answer you

Comment: Please document in a gitlab issue the details of how you did the installation and what values were set so that the issue can reproduced and fixed.

Comment: i'm waiting on gitlab account verification.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the paths by clicking on the question mark at top of page on Settings - Resource URLs which says

> These settings define the URLs used to access CiviCRM resources (CSS
>   files, Javascript files, images, etc.).
>
> You may configure these settings using absolute URLs or URL variables.

as shown in the image below.

[image]